# Exchange Server 2003 - the response from the remote server was 550 5.7.1 - alexparen fixedclix

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

In our organization we have been receiving spam email from email marketing companies namely alexparen fixedclix, so we blocked those domains on our exchange server (2003).

This resulted in being unable to receive ANY emails from google, aol, and other external services.

the failure notification shows:

Your message has been blocked.
response from remote server
550 5.7.1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ip has been blocked by alexparen.com

Disabling the block on our exchange lets the messages deliver normally.

We are very alarmed by this since it seems that somehow our emails get intercepted by that server?
Or somehow our exchange acts as being part of alexparen or fixedclix (both use same ip 45.91.93.62)

Might we be infected and acting as a bot for those marketers..?

Any information anyone might have or similar experiences are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, Exchange Server 2003 extended support ends on April 8, 2014, you'd better upgrade exchange 2003 for more support.

Comment: yeah I know that, I wouldnt be asking here though right? I'd be asking MS for support

Comment: You'd better open a ticket for MS support:)